# PhoneGap Geolocation vs Browser Geolocation

Tags: cordova, geolocation, native

Mobile browsers have geolocation built in, and when compiling a web app with PhoneGap there is the opportunity to use the PhoneGap geolocation.

Are there any advantages of using one over the other? If there are, what are they?

I would have thought that the PhoneGap geolocation would just do a call to the same browser Geolocation that I would be using if I chose to stick with standard geolocation.

All thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the web view provides it's own implementation of the W3C Geolocation API then PhoneGap leverages that implementation. When the web view does not provide an implementation we polyfil the geolocation API with our own implementation. Generally this is only used on older versions of Android.

Comment: Ah okay, so on modern browsers there's no advantage of using the PhoneGap one. Awesome! Thanks!